# RemoteCertificateNameMismatch when Fiddler is in background

Tags: c#, https, certificate, dotnet-httpclient, fiddler

I'm facing an issue that when Fiddler is on, I receive RemoteCertificateNameMismatch exception:

```
Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

Inner Exception 2:
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
```

I'm using `HttpClient` and `HttpRequestMessage` with `SencAsync` and when Fiddler is turn-off, it works. If I turn off the option for `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` (Tools > Options > HTTPS) the request also work, but not capture under fiddler so doesn't help much.

I tried to reinstall Fiddler root certificate but it still occurs.

How can I get over it since I want to inspect my traffic with Fiddler but when it's on the requests fails

Thanks

Comment: The certs generated by Fiddler are a bit outdated regarding certain properties, therefore I would recommend to install [CertMaker for iOS and Android](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons). It changes the cert generator to `BCCertMaker.BCCertMaker from CertMaker.dll` in HTTPS settings and generates a new root CA cert.

Comment: @Robert Now I'm getting `AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain` so I reset all certificates under Tools -> Options -> HTTPS -> Actions and I'm back to `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` error

Comment: Make sure the new Fiddler root CA cert is installed. If it is then your C# program may not use the Windows certificate store for retrieving trusted root CA certificates.

Comment: @Robert see my edited reply

Comment: Sorry but for debugging a `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch ` I need the Fiddler generated certificate and the URL you use in your program to see what is going wrong.

Comment: There is a way to contact you so I'll give you these two? @Robert

Comment: Sorry, but I am not providing private services.

Comment: So can you point me what does it mean "debugging `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`"? @Robert

Comment: Open the certificate generated by fiddler and check what entries are displayed  in the "Subject Alternative Name" extension. And then compare them with the URL you are sending your request to (in detail then hostname in that URL).

Comment: I can't see "Subject Alternative Name" at all, only "Subject Key Identifier" in the generated certificate (I checked it by exporting "Root Certificate to desktop" and then open it and search it under Details)

Comment: That is potentially the problem. Originally TLS uses the value from certificate "Subject", but nowadays webbrowsers and HTTP clients only use the value from "Subject Alternative Name" extension. Also make sure the original certificate on the server has a "Subject Alternative Name" extension containing the fully qualified DNS name.